# Pycharm mistakes folder for module

Tags: python, pycharm

Recently I switched computers and re-downloaded my python and pycharm, I tried activating my saved projects on the new computer, but I ran into problem, pycharm doesn't recognize the parent folder of some of the files, and mistakes it for a module.

The folder is called: "Enrichment_extra_stuff", and when I try to import file in that folder, from another file in that folder, it seems like pycharm recognize it, because it shows me all of the files inside it, but when I run the code, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Enrichment_extra_stuff'`.

Also weirdly, when I try doing explict import and just write `import fr` to import the file fr, then pycharm shows an error but when I run it, it works like it should.
I tried digging a bit on pycharm, but got confused and didn't found anything, my python interpreter version is 3.8 and I program on windows if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A folder (or better a directory) is not seen as a module, unless you put `__init__.py` file in it. This could be empty, or it should be the module content. This is Python: a module is either a file, or a directory with `__init__.py`

The second part is only for Pycharm: PyCharm is created to handle large projects, and often your program is not in the base (root) directory of your project, but in one (or more) subdirectories (e.g. `src`). So you should explicitly tell PyCharm which are the root directories. So, go to the project structure panel (the panel with the files, usually on left side), go to your "root" directory, and set with right mouse click on your base source directory: on the pop-up menu select *Mark directory as*, and then select *Source Root*.

Comment: Regarding the first part, The folder called: "Enrichment_extra_stuff" doesn't contain a file called `__init__.py`. It does contain a folder called: `__ pycache __`,  if that helps.  
 Regarding the second part, thanks, now if I try to do `import tr` from another file inside the folder, it recognizes that file.

Comment: You should create `__init__.py`. This is your module file. -- Note: PyCharm is an advanced IDE. Probably you want to start with IDLE (included in python) or spyder editors, so that you learn Python, else you can get confused on what PyCharm requires, and what are Python problems.

Comment: I added a python file called `__init__` to the folder. It still doesn't work. And by the way, I already learned Python.